# Posets: Division operation on set of real numbers

Tags: order-theory

Is the division operation on set of all real numbers a poset?

According to me, the reflexive and transitive properties are satisfied, but it is *anti-symmetric* as $\frac {0}{1}=0$, but $\frac{1}{0}=$ $\infty$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: What is your definition of poset? Usually it doesn't apply to opertions, but to relations on a given set.

Comment: Here i am not asking about the operation only, I want to know, whether set of all real numbers under the division operation forms a partial ordered set or not
Sorry for framing the question wrong

Comment: I still wonder what your definition of "poset" is. Please put that in the question.

Comment: A relation R on set A is called a partial ordering or partial order if it is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

Comment: But what is your definition of a relation? Division is usually a binary operation, not a relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that by divisibility, you mean the following relation, generalized from the usual one on integers.

> For $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we say that $a\mid b$ iff there exists an integer $k$ such that $a=kb$.

It turns out that this **isn't** a partial order: $1\mid-1$ and $-1\mid1$, while $1\neq-1$. However, if we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb R_0^+$, we can prove that this is the case.

---

**Reflexivity:**

For every real $a$, $a=1\cdot a$, so that $a\mid a$.

**Antisymmetry:**

Suppose $a\mid b$, $b\mid a$. Then, two integers $k_1$, $k_2$ must exist such that $$a=k_1b,\ b=k_2a.$$ In particular, $$a=k_1k_2a.$$ This is only possible if either $k_1=k_2=1$, or $a=0$. In both cases, $a=b$.

**Transitivity:**

If $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$, there exist integers $k_1$, $k_2$ such that $$a=k_1b,\ b=k_2c.$$ In particular, $$a=k_1k_2c,$$ so that $a\mid c$.